# is this a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is $f(x)=\sin(\operatorname{sign} xe^x)$ a measurable function ? I remember a theorem that if $f$ is a measurable function and $g$ is continuous then $g \circ f$ is measurable. Now we know that the $\sin$ function is continuous but how can I prove that $\operatorname{sign} xe^x$ is measurable?

Comment: Since $e^x$ is positive, isn't this the same as $\sin(\text{sign}(x))$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not continuous at $0$, so you cannot use your remembered theorem.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$, but the sine of a discontinuous function is usually not

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sign function outputs 1 for positive numbers, 0 for 0, and -1 for negative numbers.   As $e^x$ is always positive, it doesn't affect the sign of $x$ at all, so $\operatorname{sign} xe^x=\operatorname{sign} x$

Passing this into $\sin$ just gets you a piecewise function with 3 outputs,  $\sin(-1), 0, and \sin(1)$.  This is the sum of simple functions.  What does that tell you?